# The resource cannot be found error for MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I know there are a lot other topics like this, but from what I found, and did accordingly to the answers - I still have the error.

The Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Func", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The Controller:

```
public class FuncController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Func/

        public ActionResult Main()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Products()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And accordingly the 2 `.cshtml` View files with the `Main` and `Products` names.
In the "Project Properties->Web" I selected "Start URL" with value "http:// localhost:63497/Main". I don't get it where might the problem be, as in the other topics I found about this error, the problem was always in some of these things. But now, everything seems to be fine, and still - error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Main` is the Action method.  You need to navigate to the `Controller` and let that hit the appropriate Action.  Try navigating to:

```
http:// localhost:63497/Func/Main
```

Which is `Func` Controller.  ActionMethod `Main`

Comment: You could change the Route by excluding the controller.

Answer (score 1):

try like this..

```
    http://localhost:63497/Func/Main.
```

because the route is from controller to ActionResult.

so, here Func is the Controller and the Main is your ActionResult Method.

so, you have to use the controller first in url before the Action Method.